# ggplot2 multiple time-series plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm just learning ggplot, so my apologies if this is a really basic question.  I have data that has been aggregated by year with a few different qualities to slice on (code below will generate sample data).  I'm trying to show a few different charts: one that shows overall for a given metric, then a couple that show the same metric split across the qualities, but its not going right.  Ideally, I want to make the plot once, then call the geom layer for each of the individual charts.  I do have examples of how I want it to look in the code as well.

I'm starting to think this is a data structure issue, but really can't figure it out.

Secondary question - My years are formatted as integers, is that the best way to do that here, or should I convert them to dates?

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

#Generate Sample Data - Yearly summarized data
BaseData <- data.table(expand.grid(dataYear = rep(2010:2017),
                                   Program = c("A","B","C"),
                                   Indicator = c("0","1")))

set.seed(123)
BaseData$Metric1 <- runif(nrow(BaseData),min = 10000,100000)
BaseData$Metric2 <- runif(nrow(BaseData),min = 10000,100000)
BaseData$Metric3 <- runif(nrow(BaseData),min = 10000,100000)


BP <- ggplot(BaseData, aes(dataYear,Metric1))

BP + geom_area()  #overall Aggregate
BP + geom_area(position = "stack", aes(fill = Program)) #Stacked by Program
BP + geom_area(position = "stack", aes(fill = Indicator)) #stacked by Indicator

#How I want them to look

##overall Aggregate
BP.Agg <- BaseData[,.(Metric1 = sum(Metric1)),
                   by = dataYear]

ggplot(BP.Agg,aes(dataYear, Metric1))+geom_area()


##Stacked by Program
BP.Pro <- BaseData[,.(Metric1 = sum(Metric1)),
                   by = .(dataYear,
                          Program)]

ggplot(BP.Pro,aes(dataYear, Metric1, fill = Program))+geom_area(position = "stack")


##stacked by Indicator
BP.Ind <- BaseData[,.(Metric1 = sum(Metric1)),
                   by = .(dataYear,
                          Indicator)]

ggplot(BP.Ind,aes(dataYear, Metric1, fill = Indicator))+geom_area(position = "stack")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was right, it was an easy fix.  I should have used stat_summary instead of geom_area, here are the correct layers to add:

```
BP + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "area")
BP + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "area", position = "stack", aes(fill = Program, group = Program))
BP + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "area", position = "stack", aes(fill = Indicator, group = Indicator))
```